# How to join 2 WAV files that overlap?

Tags: wav, combine, join

I have several WAV files that overlap a couple of seconds, concretely the first 6 or 7 seconds of one are the same as last of the previous.

I'd like to join all of the chunks in just one file but taking care of the overlapping so that there are no repeated chunks.

How could that be done if at all possible?

Comment: Have you tried using audacity?

Comment: I tried, I could do it more or less manually using something called "time shift" in there but it's not very accurate and the seconds vary from one file to another. I wondered if there was anything that would find the right point when combining. Something like when you do a panorama out of several photos, but with audio files in mind.